# Debug java program

Tags: java, windows

Can anybody help me debug a java program from the command line in Windows?

Comment: I can not understand why you think eclipse is crazy, but Netbeans have a superb debugger you should at least try out.

Comment: "doesn't work"? Trust me, you'll be much more happy when you invest your time into getting Eclipse to cooperate than trying to use the command line debugger (`jdb`) of Java: it's mostly a proof-of-concept tool with no real usability features whatsoever.

Comment: We use Eclipse at work and it don't want to start debug. I need to start from command line.

Comment: If there is **really** no way to use a debugger, then add log statements. But belive me: it is like Joachim said: spending time to get the eclipse debugger running will save your time when you have the problem again.

Comment: "We use Eclipse at work and it don't want to start debug." Eclipse is not a person, it neither "wants" or "don't want" anything. If you tell us the error message, maybe we can fix the real problem.

Comment: @Damir - You must set a break-point in Eclipse - the debugger will normally only open when a code line with an active break-point is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something wrong with jdb guides found on the net like these ones : [1](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~markidis/lab11.html) [2](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-06/04-qa-0623-jdb.html) [3](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jdb-Java-Debugger-Command-and-Options.html) and [oracles documentation for jdb on windows with java 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) on jdb?

Is the change from eclipse to jdb a permanent one? Unless you must have the command line debugger, I would recommend either changing to netbeans (which has a good debugger and is a better IDE than eclipse for java programming in my opinion) or use the good old method of printing debug information to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Start your application as you would normally do, but add the following arguments:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

Now in eclipse, create a new 'remote java application' debug configuration with your project  selected. Choose localhost port 8787.

Now when you run that config, you can use the eclipse debugger even though you ran from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

To start the debugger, type

```
jdb com.example.foo.Bar
```

Once that loads up your application, type help.  You'll see what commands are available to you.  A man page for jdb can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html).